# LaTeX adds unexpected vertical space after figure with subfigures

Tags: floats, vertical-spacing

I'm using the document class IEEEtrans with conference settings for a paper I'm writing. When I add a figure with subfigures LaTeX unexpectedly adds vertical space that makes the entire document look weird and add more space in unexpected places. (see Figure for the example)
[image]

As you can see in the figure, between the horses and the text there is a vertical space that shouldn't be there.

Code of that piece:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
    \centering
    \subfigure[Original]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{images/Fotos_caballos/caballos.png}
        \label{caballos_original}
    }
    \subfigure[Demo using recommended scales]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{images/Fotos_caballos/caballos_out_orig.png}
        \label{caballos_demo}
    }
    \\
    \subfigure[Demo using scales 3, 4 and 6]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{images/Fotos_caballos/caballos_out_346.png}
        \label{caballos_demo_346}
    }
    \subfigure[Python]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{images/Fotos_caballos/output_python_caballos.png}
        \label{caballos_python}
    }
    \\
    \subfigure[FPGA]
    {
        \includegraphics[width=1.4in]{images/Fotos_caballos/output_fpga_caballos.png}
        \label{caballos_FPGA}
    }
    \caption{Horses image comparison. }
    \label{caballos}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{caballos} shows how the MSRCP algorithm works on a badly contrasted image with certain shadowed elements.
```

Packages and options used for the entire document:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\addbibresource{cite.bib} %Imports bibliography file
\setlength{\dblfloatsep}{1in}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
```

Comment: it's impossible to test the fragments posted or say why the space appears. presumably code not shown is preventing anything else appear on the page. But if you use the command defined by `\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}` there  is absolutely no chance of debugging anything, that will break latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't want to add the entire document as it is  more than 600 lines of LaTeX code. Also, I used removelatexerror as a walkaround to another problem I had with using floats with algorithmic package. Do you suggest to post the 600 lines of code of the document?

Comment: 600 lines is better than an unusable test but it is unlikely that you need to post more than a 20 or 30.  make a copy of the document, use `example-image` so that we have the images delete everything after the problem page and everything that you can delete before it while still showing the problem, then delete any packages that are not  used in the reduced example.  delete a (say) five line paragraph and replace by `a\\a\\a\\a\\a` once it is small enough to post and shows the problem, add it to your question.

Comment: No there is no chance that `\removelatexerror` ever does any good. Suppressing errors is a bad idea in general but `\@latex@error` takes two arguments and that redefines it just to throw away one so leaving the second argument to appear in some random unexpected place.

Comment: While the IEEEtran manual doesn't say anything about the ffloat package (it does mention algorithm2e), every package you add increases the likelihood of finding incompatibilities.  BTW, the subfigue package is obsolete.